# How to convert string having scientific notation to a float without loosing precision?

Tags: python-3.x, precision

I have a string that I need to convert to a float for me to work on.

```
num = "2.769999999999999574e+00"
```

If I do a float operation, the precision is gone

```
print(float(num))  # 2.7699999999999996
```

If I use a Decimal class ,even then the precision is gone

```
from decimal import Decimal
print(Decimal(num))  # 2.769999999999999574
```

It seems Decimal is only able to retain the precision if the number supplied is a float in the first place

```
print(Decimal(2.769999999999999574e+00))  # 2.769999999999999573674358543939888477325439453125
```

How do I maintain precision while converting a number from string to float?

Comment: What do you mean by "the precision is gone"? You convert the number `2.769999999999999574` to decimal and get `2.769999999999999574`. What do you expect?

Comment: [No, converting that to float doesn't lose any precision](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P680V8FWQclIz9zMEhmYmpukahsYKHEVFGXmlWioV1vpmRrUquul5RflJpZopOXkA0mgZk1Nzf//AQ). They're just not displayed.

Comment: @user202729 updated the code.Here 2.769999999999999574e+00 is a very large number and I want to keep it as large as I can possibly keeping the 'e' notation.Currently only Decimal is able to give me a very large number but only when the given number is not a string.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The exponent is e00.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I only took one of the numbers as an example.There are numbers with with e02 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Decimal(2.769999999999999574e+00)` doesn't "retain precision". It only exposes the [limitations of floating point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). The number you specify does not have an exact bit representation in memory, and is approximated to some degree, accounting for the extended precision you see here. This is a limitation of your (and any other) CPU. `Decimal("2.769999999999999574e+00")` on the other hand, is actually a more correct representation of your quantity than passing an actual float.

Comment: Yes I see, the Decimal is actually giving a more correct representation than a float.